# Cant call function in import class

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I'm a beginner. Cant call `go_home_page` in test.js

```
// test.js
var homePage = require('./home_page');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .build();

home = new homePage(driver);
home.go_home_page();



// home_page.js
    class homePage{
        constructor(driver){
            this.driver = driver;
        }
        go_home_page(){
            this.driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        }
    }

TypeError: homePage is not a constructor
```

How can I call `go_home_page()` use import and class?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `module.exports` to first export the module from `home_page.js`

Comment: Thanks! You save my life!

Comment: I have added it as answer. Please upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `module.exports` to export the module that you want to use in your `test.js` . So you could do something like this

```
module.exports={
homePage1 : homePage
 }
```

And then refer it in your code in `test.js` file